# How to extend page content to screen bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a Joomla site and I'm having a problem extending a page to the bottom of the screen. Here is a pic of the page: [image] page html:

```
<div id="free_trial_page">
  <div id="free_trial_container">
    <div id="free_title_block"><p id="free_title_text">Welcome to the <span class="hilite_text">Free</span>Introductory Course</p></div>
    <div id="free_title_block"><p id="free_title_text">ยินดีต้อนรับ สู่ คอร์สทดลองเรียน <span class="hilite_text">ฟรี</span>ไทย</p></div>
    <div id="free_item"  class="free_items">
        <p class="free_content_title"> We hope you will enjoy learning English in these pages</p>
         <p class="free_content_title">เราหวังว่าท่านจะสนุกกับการเรียนภาษาอังกฤษจากหน้าเหล่านี่</p>
        <p class="free_content">Please click thumbnails to see videos</p>
        <p class="welcome_vids">
          <span><a id="welcome_vids" href="index.php/sg-video-2"><img src="/templates/beez_20/images/ws_wst2.png" width="160" height="90"></a></span>        
         ....   
        </p>
        <p class="welcome_vids">
          <span><a id="welcome_vids" href="index.php/sg-video-2"><img src="/templates/beez_20/images/ws_wst2.png" width="160" height="90"></a></span>        
         ....
        </p>         
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

There is no footer on the page. I've tried  set min-height to 100% as recommended online but this hasn't worked and I'm not sure which div to attach it to. There is no footer on the page.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't exactly understand your problematic, but you could set your #free_trial_page to position: fixed; overflow: auto; with height: 100%; width: 100%; top:0; left:0; -OR- simply set it to height: 100vh;

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't give you a tick but thanks anyhow for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vh` unit. Set you height to `100vh` and you div will fit on your page screen.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it worked perfectly. Only 1 minute between you guys but since you put up the answer, you got the tick.